# Is it possible to customize vxg mobile video player by using Phonegap?

Tags: cordova

There is a good mobile video player is provided by http://www.videoexpertsgroup.com/

There can be customize the **mobile video player** by using it's SDK. And the mobile video player SDK is written in java. I am not a JAVA programmer. I want to customize the this player by using phonegap(javascript). Is it possible to customize that mobile video player by using Phonegap?

Is there any alternate that I can customize this player without using JAVA?.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to create a [phonegap/cordova plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html).